# Boundary conditions in differential equations in Modelica

Tags: modelica

I need help with solving differential equations with modelica. particularly with the boundary conditions which in my case are not defined at z = 0.

The equation is really simple:

a*y'' - y' - b*y = 0

boundary conditions:

a*y' = y - 1 at z = 0;

y' = 0 at z = 1;

I know the 'initial equation' and 'start' commands but they are defined at z = 0. How do you define the boundary conditions at other z values.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to solve is a boundary value problem (as far as I can tell, you didn't really define what `z` was).  Modelica was designed to handle initial value problems.  As such, I don't think you'll be able to solve this problem directly in Modelica.  What you might be able to do is wrap an optimization loop *around* the initial value problem solutions to try and satisfy your additional constraint.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I will follow your advice